# Can't use custom guard to call auth protected endpoints in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, authentication, axios, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 7 for a new project where I have different types of users, for example `customers`.

I allow customers to login via the UI and then have specific endpoints which I want this `customers` guard to be able to call, however it doesn't seem to be working. Any assistance would be appreciated.

My guard and providers are defined as follows:

```
'customers' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'customers',
],

'api-customers' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'customers',
    'hash' => false,
],
```

The routes that I'm trying to reach with Axios are defined in `routes/api.php` and I've tried a few different middleware none which have worked:

```
auth:api
auth.customers
```

`auth:api` is the default guard I tried, I then created an `AuthedCustomers.php` middleware (code below) that checks if `Auth::guard('customers')->check()` returns true, and defined it as a route middleware with the key `auth.customers` as shown above.

**AuthedCustomers.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthCustomers
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('customers')->check() === false) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
            ], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My request seems to have an XSRF token applied to it, here is the full request:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,de;q=0.4
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkY4ZDZCeGd6cUZHcHF3TEpuY0U0M0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0xZeFpxQUZmTlNPWEZ6bUF2SUtNdkEyN2pwejZLenNmdEZCVzdvYytndlVteGs3T3FSc00wMTRXRHB4bGhNWCIsIm1hYyI6ImE2NmM4MWQ1NDEyYjNiMjYxYjM1YTBlMWY5OWQ4M2ZhZTQ5MmRjYzA2ODA0YWYyNTc5N2YwNTE3NDE1ZTU2ZDYifQ%3D%3D; cradlemoney_session=eyJpdiI6ImcraW5QdGplL1p0dGhnK2Q0THBZYkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibGZ2UDNkZytoS2NBdEhsbGVKbnh0b0ZWTm9UTjNLVUdwSFZtazBidEgvSXdKNEhqQzBjV3FpaXdqdEp2amZFZSIsIm1hYyI6Ijk2NDY4YTdlOWYzOTJlODI0M2RjMGI2ZThjNDI5ZDBjMzk5ZGZjYjc1ODk4ZGYxMGQ2OTQzYmYxZDEyNWRmZjIifQ%3D%3D
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IkY4ZDZCeGd6cUZHcHF3TEpuY0U0M0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0xZeFpxQUZmTlNPWEZ6bUF2SUtNdkEyN2pwejZLenNmdEZCVzdvYytndlVteGs3T3FSc00wMTRXRHB4bGhNWCIsIm1hYyI6ImE2NmM4MWQ1NDEyYjNiMjYxYjM1YTBlMWY5OWQ4M2ZhZTQ5MmRjYzA2ODA0YWYyNTc5N2YwNTE3NDE1ZTU2ZDYifQ==
```

Request:

```
Request URL: /api/customer/6
Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Unauthenticated"}
```

I have no problem when using the default guard to protect api routes using `auth:api` but I cannot for the life of me get axios authentication to work for my `customers` guard, any help to try and diagnose my problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: version of laravel passport?

Comment: I have same problem.. Could you find a solution?